# Time data 'None' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Here I have values with time and I used python to plot the graph import from Excel.csv file. Here I have some rows with none. When I code it , it is showing error that time data none is not match with '%H:%M:%S'. 
Here I include the time with values table.

> x data    y data  x1 data y1 data x2 data y2 data
>   0:06:15   141 0:08:00 131 0:06:45 136
>   0:09:25   95  0:08:15 117 0:09:30 95
>   0:11:00   149 0:08:30 109 0:11:30 139
>   0:13:50   85  0:08:45 103 0:13:30 95
>   0:16:25   135 0:09:00 97  0:15:25 105
>   0:19:00   63  None    None    0:18:00 97
>   0:20:00   111 None    None    0:19:30 100
>   0:22:05   115 None    None    0:22:15 115
>   0:23:40   287 None    None    None    None

My code is,

```js
condition = ""
weight = ""
height = ""
date = ""

label1 = ""
label2 = ""
label3 = ""

x  = []
y  = []
x1 = []
y1 = []
x2 = []
y2 = []


def convertTime(s):
 tm = time.strptime(s, "%H:%M:%S")
 return datetime.datetime(date.tm_year,date.tm_mon, date.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec)

with open('data.csv') as csv_file:
  csv_data = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
  row_num = 0
  for row in csv_data:
    if(row_num == 0):
      condition = row[0]
      weight = row[1]
      height = row[2]
    elif(row_num == 1):
      date = time.strptime(row[0], "Date:-%Y/%m/%d")
    elif(row_num == 2):
      label1 = row[0]
      label2 = row[1]
      label3 = row[2]
    elif(row_num > 3): #Data starts here
      x.append(convertTime(row[0]))
      y.append(int(row[1]))
      x1.append(convertTime(row[2]))
      y1.append(int(row[3]))
      x2.append(convertTime(row[4]))
      y2.append(int(row[5]))
    row_num = row_num + 1

plt.plot(x,y,label=label1)
plt.stem(x1,y1,'C1-.','C1o',label=label2)
plt.stem(x2,y2,'C2-.','C2o',label=label3)
plt.legend()
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()

print(x)
print(y)
```

and my error is,

> ValueError: time data 'None' does not match format '%H:%M:%.
>   Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's your question here? You pretty obviously have `None` values. You know you have `None` values. You try to parse those `None` values as datetime strings, and you get an error telling you that doesn't work with `None` values, because they're not datetime strings.

Comment: You should not put conditions in paranthesis. This actually creates a tuple. Just separate the condition from the `if` with white space... Regarding your problem, read about [Exception Handling](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement)... When you reply to a comment, start with "@UserName", if you want to address a certain user.

Comment: @ Sven Krüger, sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is parse `None` to a `datetime` object but before that, you need to tell datetime the format of your date

In your code here -

```
def convertTime(s):
    # when s = None, you get that error 
    tm = time.strptime(s, "%H:%M:%S")
    return datetime.datetime(date.tm_year,date.tm_mon, date.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec)
```

To handle this error you could check if `s` is `not None` like -

```
def convertTime(s):
    if s:
        tm = time.strptime(s, "%H:%M:%S")
        return datetime.datetime(date.tm_year,date.tm_mon, date.tm_mday,
    return None
```

But even then, **your graph will be wrong** because you are **missing data** in columns `x1` and `x2`. But I think that's all you can do or get the data right.

Or you could check if row contains `None` in those columns and put `continue` in your `for` loop and skip the row entirely, like -

```
elif(row_num > 3): #Data starts here
    if None in row:
        row_num += 1
        continue # This will make you skip the row
    x.append(convertTime(row[0]))
    y.append(int(row[1]))
    x1.append(convertTime(row[2]))
    y1.append(int(row[3]))
    x2.append(convertTime(row[4]))
    y2.append(int(row[5]))
```

You'll skip ticks with this but you'll be able to plot the graph

Comment: I'm not able to plot it. It is showing an error like,  File "<ipython-input-53-a1c072c3722b>", line 37
    if `None` in row:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @kasuri remove quotes around `None` and see if your indentation is correct and let me know

Comment: I removed all the none and run my code then it is showing error like, ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'

Comment: I got an error ,  row_num += 1
          
(num) -IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Make sure your spaces are correct, that's what the error says

Comment: Your indentation is still wrong it means. Space everything with 4 spaces. Look at [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?#tabs-or-spaces)

Comment: I found the answer. Thank you all.